# how to stop a popup form from loading on any random click in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, forms, popup

on my WordPress site, a popup form is available. I linked that popup form with "get a quote" button on the homepage. when I visit the site and click on a random link or button form starts to load automatically and then disappears. I want to load the popup form only on the button click not on any random click. could you help me to solve this issue?
I looked for the answer on various search engines but was still clueless.
below is the site address.

[www.elegancesol.com](http://www.elegancesol.com)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour because of your setup. Since you didn’t post your javascript it is impossible to see where you made a mistake.

Comment: it is a wordpress site and no explicit js is used

Comment: Then what is your setup? What popup form? Are you using a plugin? is in integrated in your theme? It would have saved me time if you would have explained. I cannot guess how you made this...